# Ruby on Rails dynamic previous/next buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a site where we have a list of "dprojects" in an index. Using the 'Ransack' gem, we're sorting this index by column headers as well as any other parameters specified at the top (eg: Projects assigned to Bob, sorted by due_date). The user then presses the 'search' button and the index is updated to show the specified projects in the specified order. Here's where my question comes in-

If a user clicks on a "dproject" to edit it, they see a 'next' and 'previous' button to go to the next and previous projects. However, these buttons always direct you to the next and previous projects by project id only.

So if the user sorts the table to show only Bob's projects, the listed projects might be project #'s 12, 16, 22, and 34. But if you click on the next button from project 12, it will direct you to project 13 instead of the desired project 16. I imagine I have to somehow access the array of projects being iterated through on the index and tell the buttons to direct the user to the next project in the array instead of the next project by id- but I'm not sure how to approach that.

Model code:

```
def previous_dproject
    Dproject.where(["id < ?", id]).last
end

def next_dproject
    Dproject.where(["id > ?", id]).first
end
```

Controller code:

```
def index
  params[:q].reject { |_, v| v.blank? } if params[:q]

  @q = Dproject.ransack(params[:q])
  @dprojects = @q.result.includes(:school)
  respond_with(@dprojects)
end

def edit
  @dproject = Dproject.find(params[:id])
  @options = School.order(:name).where.not(school_type_id: nil).
  collect do |s|
    [s.name, s.id]
  end
end
```

View:

```
<%= link_to("Previous Project", @dproject.previous_dproject) if @dproject.previous_dproject %> |
<%= link_to("Next Project", @dproject.next_dproject) if @dproject.next_dproject %>
```

Comment: Although what you're asking here could be done in the backend, e.g. using the session object, I would strongly suggest using frontend (JavaScript) logic for it, as this is a classic case for the kind of state which should exist only in the frontend. If you don't want to have complex frontend logic I would suggest not having these back/next buttons at all.

Comment: Can you show  how sorting (filtering) of projects is made?